# iTextSharp : Pdf Rectangular radio buttons becomes circular button when filling data

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to fill an existing PDF. There is a rectangular radio buttons which I am trying to fill. But when I put value in it. The appearance changes from rectangular to circular.

This is my code :

```
 using (var existingFileStream = new FileStream(existingFileNameWithPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var newFileStream = new FileStream(fileNameNew, FileMode.Create))
            {
                // Open existing PDF
                var pdfReader = new PdfReader(existingFileStream);

                // PdfStamper, which will create
                var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newFileStream,'\0', true);
                var form = stamper.AcroFields;
                form.SetField("Application for Export", "New");
                stamper.Close();
                pdfReader.Close();
            }
```

The Pdf I am trying to make is similar to this pdf : https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Form/FAA_Form_8130-1.pdf

Comment: can you attach the PDF that you are having issue with?

Comment: I have already given the link.. I can post this again : https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Form/FAA_Form_8130-1.pdf

Comment: I don't see any radio button changing its appearance.. which field are you talking about? are you trying to fill the PDF using c# code? or do you mean to say its changing after you download and try to select a radio button?

Comment: Yes.. I am using iTextSharp in C# code. Also trying to update the value of : 1. Application is made for an export certificate of airworthiness to cover the product(s) described below which (are): - **New**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form fields in PDFs are a bit unique. They define how they should look in their on, off, and sometimes even focused (on, being actively pressed) state using explicit drawing operations.

When filling forms iText has to create these values as there is no guarantee they exist (especially when you create the form with iText!) and iText inserts a "typical" appearance. For radio buttons this is a circular button. Note that, at least for me, the circular button only appears when I am actively clicking the button.

You have two options- trust that the PDF in question already has appearance states and disable generating them (the PDF you listed does have these)

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUT_FILE);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE));
    AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
    fields.setGenerateAppearances(false); //Add this line
    fields.setField("Application for Export", "New");
    stamper.close();
```

Alternatively you can manually write the drawing operations and insert it into the form field's appearance state yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If there are text fields to be filled it needs setGenerateAppearences=true. This code helps to resolve-

```
 AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
 fields.GenerateAppearances = false;
 fields.SetField("IndividualChk", "On");
 fields.GenerateAppearances = true;
 fields.SetField("InvestorName", "Mensh");
 stamper.FormFlattening = true;
```